# Cannot find module 'angular2-csv/Angular2-csv

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, npm-install

I Install the `npm install --save angular2-csv@0.2.5` package from npm.
It works on my local server but It gives error on prod i.e  **Cannot find module 'angular2-csv/Angular2-csv'**. I'm using angular version 5.

Comment: can you post code sample where you import 'agnular2-csv', and package json, build logs?

Comment: component.ts :
import { Angular2Csv } from 'angular2-csv/Angular2-csv';  //import in component
new Angular2Csv(data,'Filename', options);  // declare it in same component

and in package.json:
"angular2-csv": "^0.2.5",